# Maximum of COUNT by group and joining on EQUALS and NOT EQUALS condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, common-table-expression

I am working on a scenario where I need to get counts grouped by UserID and then obtain the maximum count obtained from the result set of the grouping.

This maximum count will then be used to calculate percentages against each of the rows obtained from the result set of grouping.

Here is an example:

This is the sample data I have:

```
 Users Table:   
  UserID        CountAsApproved  
    1                   1
    2                   1   
    1                   1
    2                   1
    3                   1
    3                   0
    4                   1
    1                   1
    4                   0

    Grouping Result:

  UserID            Counts
    1                 3
    2                 2
    3                 1
    4                 1
```

I then need to get the maximum of the count (in this case max count is 3)
and then calculate percentages as follows:

```
 UserID         Counts      MaxCount            Percentage
    1             3           3            (Count/MaxCount)*100
    2             2           3                 2/3 * 100
    3             1           3                 1/3 * 100
    4             1           3                 1/3 * 100
```

I currently have the query like this:

```
    ;WITH Groups_CTE AS(
        SELECT UserID, COUNT(CountAsApproved) as Counts
        FROM Users 
        GROUP BY UserID),
MaxCount_CTE AS 
(
        SELECT MAX(Counts) AS MaxCount
        FROM Groups_CTE
)
SELECT 
        gc.UserID,
        gc.Counts,
        mc.MaxCount,
        CASE WHEN CAST(( ( gc.Counts
                                   / mc.MaxCount ) * 100 ) AS INT) = 0
                     THEN 1
                     ELSE CAST(( ( gc.Counts
                                   / mc.MaxCount ) * 100 ) AS INT)
                END AS Percentage
FROM    Groups_CTE gc CROSS JOIN MaxCount_CTE mc
```

The above query is yielding the same result when I do an Inner join on the below condition instead of a CROSS JOIN

```
FROM    Groups_CTE gc JOIN MaxCount_CTE mc
ON gc.Counts <> mc.MaxCount OR gc.Counts = mc.MaxCount
```

I just wanted to check if there is a better way of doing this in performance point of view or in reducing the number of lines of code. I get the same results with either of the joins and also when I used `CROSS APPLY` without a condition.
I am also a bit hesitant about using two CTEs.

Let me know your thoughts and suggestions in improvising this code.

> If it may help, the Users table on which we perform these operations may contain rows ranging in thousands.

Comment: What is the point of <> or =? Every single row will meet that criteria. It will either be equal OR not equal unless it is NULL, which it can't since it is a count. You have effectively created a cross join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [**`max() over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
select 
    userid
  , Counts     = sum(countasapproved)
  , MaxCount   = max(sum(countasapproved)) over()
  , Percentage = sum(countasapproved+.0)/max(sum(countasapproved)) over()
from Users 
group by userid
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TLG73597

returns:

```
+--------+--------+----------+------------+
| userid | Counts | MaxCount | Percentage |
+--------+--------+----------+------------+
|      1 |      3 |        3 | 1,000000   |
|      2 |      2 |        3 | 0,666666   |
|      3 |      1 |        3 | 0,333333   |
|      4 |      1 |        3 | 0,333333   |
+--------+--------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: I am not really sure, but are calculating the max and sum each time costly operations?

Comment: @Kashyap No, that's not how that works. The `over()` only operates on the result set, and an identical expression is only evaluated once.

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions on your aggregate results:

```
select 
  userid, 
  sum(countasapproved) as counts, 
  max(sum(countasapproved)) over () as maxcount,
  sum(countasapproved) * 100.0 / max(sum(countasapproved)) over () as percentage
from users
group by userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the volumne of data, a sub-query may be a little more performant

```
Select *
      ,MaxCount = max(Cnt) over ()
      ,PctCnt   = (Cnt+0.0) / max(Cnt) over ()
 From  (
        Select UserID
              ,Cnt = sum(CountAsApproved)
         From YourTable 
         Group By UserID
       ) A
```

Returns

```
UserID  Cnt MaxCount    PctCnt
1       3   3           1.000000000000
2       2   3           0.666666666666
3       1   3           0.333333333333
4       1   3           0.333333333333
```